# ASP.NET Session returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, null, object-reference

I am developing asp.net web app (Web-Forms) in which i am using Session to store user related data. Though i am storing data in session object when i am trying to retrieve it gives me error :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here's class where I'am using method:

```
public partial class CheckoutReview : System.Web.UI.Page, IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
```

and here's code where error appears:

```
public partial class CheckoutReview : System.Web.UI.Page, IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                NVPAPICaller payPalCaller = new NVPAPICaller();
                string retMsg = "";
                string token = "";
                string PayerID = "";
                NVPCodec decoder = new NVPCodec();
                token = Session["token"].ToString(); <---
```

Set Session["token"]:

```
public partial class CheckoutStart : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NVPAPICaller payPalCaller = new NVPAPICaller();
            string retMsg = "";
            string token = "";

            if (Session["payment_amt"] != null)
            {
                string amt = Session["payment_amt"].ToString();

                bool ret = payPalCaller.ShortcutExpressCheckout(amt, ref token, ref retMsg);
                if (ret)
                {
                    Session["token"] = token;
                    Response.Redirect(retMsg);
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect("CheckoutError.aspx?" + retMsg);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("CheckoutError.aspx?ErrorCode=AmtMissing");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Where is the code that sets session["token"]?

Comment: Updated in description

Comment: So is `Session["payment_amt"]` not null?

Comment: Nope, it's not null. I check it with debugger.

Comment: Okay, problem solved, i make stupid mistake ;)